# Python Wand RMSE comparison

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

Is it possible to do an RMSE image compare with wand?

If not with wand, than perhaps another Python/ImageMagick binding?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587561/how-to-compare-between-the-two-images-and-highlight-the-difference/55638611#55638611